# bool and SetActive could be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**error :'bool' does not contain a definition for 'SetActive' and no accessible extension method 'SetActive' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject deadmenu;
    public float health;

    public bool dead = false;
    public bool oyundurdurma = false;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
    
        public void oyunuDurdur() {
        if(oyundurdurma == false) {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            oyundurdurma = true;
        }else {
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            oyundurdurma = false;
        }
    
        }


    public void getDamage(float damage)
    {
        if (health - damage >= 0)
        {
            health -= damage;
        }
        else
        {
            health = 0;
        }
        amIdead();
    }
    void amIdead()
    {
        if (health == 0)
        {
            dead = true;
            deadmenu.SetActive(dead);
            oyundurdurma.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript

Comment: I think this `Unity`, can you update the tags with the right language and technology?

Comment: A bool does not have setactive. The error code seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `SetActive()` method on a boolean variable `oyundurdurma`. This is why you have an error. `SetActive()` is for `GameObject` object.

Comment: I wrote but it didn't change

Comment: ok how should i write

Comment: If you just want to set the boolean : `oyundurdurma = true`, but I'm not sure what you're aiming for.

Comment: "oyundurdurma" means to pause the game

Comment: I suggest you to read this because it depends on how you want to implement this : https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-pause-the-game-in-unity/

Comment: ok very very thanks